# C# generic indexer wont return a string

Tags: c#, generics, return, indexer

Here's the class with the generic indexer

```
 public class IndexThis<T>
{
    T[] MainArr = new T[100];

    public IndexThis(params T[] Arrz)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Arrz.Length; i++)
        {
            MainArr[i] = Arrz[i];
        }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (MainArr[index] == null) return "myStringHere";  //compile error
            return MainArr[index]; 
        }

        private set { }
    }
}
```

Trying to cast it to (T) or using "as T" still gives me the compile time error, it appears I can't really remember what am I missing here

Comment: There is no gurantee of converting `string` to `T`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T`, as it is currently unconstrained, can be anything. The indexer needs to return `T` and calling code will expect an instance of type `T`.

Let's say you use the type...

```
var foo = new IndexThis<Giraffe>();
```

Your indexer is now essentially:

```
public Giraffe this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (MainArr[index] == null) return "myStringHere";  //compile error
        return MainArr[index]; 
    }
}
```

Which of course makes no sense.

If you need to return a value, consider returning `default( T )`. Alternatively, throw an exception.

Comment: Ok since I already feel dumb enough i'll go on and ask you what would have been the best way to do what I was actually thinking, instead of using T as a return type changing it to object would have made the trick ? Or possibly the best way would have been calling a method after the if statement that wrote on console the supposed string ?

Comment: No need to feel dumb. The best approach depends on what you are trying to do. If you just want diagnostic info, throw an exception or log the value (console is fine), whatever works. Yes, you *could* return an object, but then what would the caller do with that info? They would need to check the type of value that you had returned to do anything useful.

Comment: Would have worked as a object since I was simply calling the indexer on console.writeline just for learning purposes. Thanks anyway!